# How to run function after another function (UI form)?

Tags: google-apps-script

My problem is I need to push the button `buttonGet` to run `function test (e)` but only after three function executed (`validateName (e), validateVk (e), validateEmail (e)`) and appeared the new data in the form that will be checked by the `function test (e)`. 
All this should be done by clicking once `buttonGet`, is it possible? 
Thank you for your time!

```
function doGet() {

            ...

              var handler = app.createServerHandler('_processSubmittedData').addCallbackElement(panel); 
              var handler1 = app.createServerHandler('refresh').addCallbackElement(panel); 
              var h1 = app.createServerHandler('validateEmail').addCallbackElement(panel);

              var h2 = app.createServerHandler('validateVk').validateMatches(vk, 'vk.com').addCallbackElement(panel); 
              var h21 = app.createClientHandler().validateNotMatches(vk, 'vk.com')
              .forTargets(empty6)
              .setVisible(true);

              var h3 = app.createServerHandler('validateName').validateLength(fname, 2, 100).addCallbackElement(panel); 
              var h31 = app.createClientHandler().validateNotLength(fname, 2, 100)
              .forTargets(empty1)
              .setVisible(true);


              button.addMouseUpHandler(handler);
          buttonGet.addClickHandler(h1)
        .addClickHandler(h2)
        .addClickHandler(h21)
        .addClickHandler(h3)
        .addClickHandler(h31)
        .addClickHandler(handler1);

        ...

              return app;
            }

function refresh(e) {
              ...

            }

function validateEmail(e){
              var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
              var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
              var email = e.parameter.email;
              Logger.log(email);
              if(emailPattern.test(email) == false) {
                app.getElementById('empty4');
                 }
              else {
                    app.getElementById('empty4').setText("Email принят!").setStyleAttribute('color', '#339900').setVisible(true)
                    app.getElementById('empty41').setText("ок");
                   }
              return app;
            }
function validateVk (e) {
              var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
              app.getElementById('empty6').setText('VK принят!').setStyleAttribute('color', '#339900').setVisible(true);
              app.getElementById('empty61').setText("ок");
              return app
            }
function validateName (e) {
              var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
              app.getElementById('empty1').setText('Здравствуйте, ' + e.parameter.fname + '!').setStyleAttribute('color', '#339900').setVisible(true);
              app.getElementById('empty11').setText("ок");
              return app
            }
function test(e) {
              var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
              var L1 = e.parameter.empty41
              var L2 = e.parameter.empty61
              var L3 = e.parameter.empty11
              if (L1 == 'ок' && L2 == 'ок' && L3 == 'ок') {
                app.getElementById('cb1').setVisible(true);
                app.getElementById('terms').setVisible(true);
              }
              return app
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think the best way to do it is to check directly each form element with a addChangeHandler. The addChangeHandler can check if all the fields are correctly filled in and only once it's done you can press the submit button.
Here a working example:

```
function doGet(){
 var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("testData");
  var panel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var txt = app.createTextBox().setId("elementToTest").setName("elementToTest").addChangeHandler(handler);
  handler.addCallbackElement(txt);
  var but = app.createButton("submit").setId("submitButton").setEnabled(false);
  panel.add(txt).add(but);
  app.add(panel);
  return(app);
}

function testData(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var val = e.parameter.elementToTest;
  if(val=="test"){
    app.getElementById("submitButton").setEnabled(true);
  }
  return(app);
}
```

I Hope I correctly answered your question.

Harold

Comment: Thank you, Harold. This is exactly what I wanted to find!